# Changing background row color in reportviewer based on column value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, reportviewer

Currently I am using this

```
=iif(Fields!washCount.Value<=50,"LimeGreen","Yellow")
```

but I want to use it like when wash count is less then 50 row will green and if washcount if greater than 50 but less than 80 row will yellow ,same as id washcount is greater then 80 row became red.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting the Iif statements, e.g. like this:

```
=Iif(Fields!washCount.Value <= 50, "LimeGreen", 
    Iif(Fields!washCount.Value <= 80, "Yellow", "Red"))
```

Comment: I was going to use 
Switch(Fields!washCount.Value <= 50 ,"Green",Fields!washCount.Value <= 80, "Yellow")

But your answer worked for me Thank you so much.